# How to write a batch to roll up specific children?

Tags: apex, batch

**Requirement**

I have a question regarding batch apex.i have a field usageEnd date on asset object. If this usage end date is today, then change the status to Expired. Else keep the status purchased. Now count number of purchased and expired status and display on account object.

**Attempted Code**

```
global class CountAssets implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

  global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
      return Database.getQueryLocator([Select AccountId,Name, Quantity,Status s,UsageEndDate from Asset where Status='Purchased' or Status='Expired' ]);
  }


  global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<Account> scope) {
     Account[] updates = new Account[] {};
     for (Asset a:AccountId) 
     {
     if(Status=='Expired')
        updates.add(new Account(Id =(Id) ar.get('a'),Number_of_inactiveAssets__c = (Decimal) ar.get('c')));
        else
        updates.add(new Account(Id =(Id) ar.get('a'),Number_of_activeAssets__c = (Decimal) ar.get('c')));
    }
    update updates;
  }

  public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Write a batch apex which will run daily, retrieve asset records then check your conditions and accordingly update their count on their respective Account record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a loop on `Scope` list
Try changing your execute method to something like this.

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<Asset> scope) {
     for(Asset a : scope)
         {
            if(a.status == 'Expired')
                //your logic
            else
                //your logic
         }
         update scope;

}
```